# Android live wallpaper call back to preview layout

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I want to come back to preview layout of live wallpaper after setting it .
How can I do it by android code ?

Comment: After setting it? What do you mean by that?

Comment: In livewallpaper it has two button setting and set . When I click button setting it will call preference screen . I want to come back to livewallpaper preview mode when I click any item in preference screen . Thanks in advance !

Comment: How did you set it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your user will expect or appreciate the abrupt transition, but here's the code anyway!  Put it in your SettingsActivity.java, where you call `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings)`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key)
{
    // This will close your settings activity when any preference changes.
    finish();
}
```